# Spring 4.x and spring data mongo db 2.x compatibility

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

Can we use spring version 4.3 and spring data mongo db version 2.2.3 to connect to mongo db 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

See [Changes in version 2.2.3.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.2.x/changelog.txt):

> DATAMONGO-2430 - Upgrade to mongo-java-driver 3.11.2.

Then see [Java Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility), where it's stated that Java driver 3.11 is compatible with MongoDB 4.2.